# How to drag / slide a element in QML without changing its x,y position?

Tags: qt, slider, qml

I am working on development of a UI where i am required to implement something similar effect of dragging the status bar in any smart phone.

This should slide the element downwards on click.(which means its height is increased)

I tried using the following code to take of " NO x,y values change "  of the element

```
MouseArea{
    id : zone2MouseArea
    anchors.fill : parent

    drag.target: zone2ID
    drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
    drag.minimumY: 0
    drag.maximumY: 0.1

}
```

and onYChanged () i increased the height.

However this does not suffice my requirement. I need to slide the element changing its view interms of height without changing its x,y values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made a basic example. Hope it helps. I dont have an IDE with me as of now, so please check for syntax errors

```
import QtQuick 1.1

Rectangle
{
    width: 560
    height: 560
    color: "blue"

    Rectangle
    {
       id: slider
       width: parent.width
       height: parent.height
       y: - parent.height * .90
       color: "yellow"

       property bool isAtTop: true

       Behavior on y { NumberAnimation { duration: 300 } }

       Text
       {
           text: qsTr("12:34 PM")
           anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
           color: "black"
       }

       Text
       {
           text: qsTr("Battery | Wifi | Updates")
           anchors.centerIn: parent
           color: "black"
           font.pixelSize: 25
       }

       MouseArea
       {
           id: draggingMouse
           anchors.fill : parent
           drag.target: parent
           drag.axis: Drag.YAxis
           drag.minimumY: - parent.height * .90
           drag.maximumY: 0

           onReleased:
           {
               if ( true == slider.isAtTop )
               {
                   if( slider.y < - parent.height * .80 )
                       slider.y = - parent.height * .90
                   else
                   {
                       slider.y = 0
                       slider.isAtTop = false
                   }
               }

               else
               {
                   if( slider.y < - parent.height * .20 )
                   {
                       slider.y = - parent.height * .90
                       slider.isAtTop = true
                   }

                   else
                   {
                       slider.y = 0
                   }
               }

           }
       }
    }
}
```